# Setting first visible option as default

Tags: javascript

I have a filter method that whenever a date and time is changed, the function `checkRoom();` is called. This function basically filters some options which is completely working. My problem now is that even though the option is filtered, the filtered value is still the now showing on top. Now, how can I set the first visible option as default value?

I have tried using these both these codes but it is not working.
`document.getElementById("room4").value = ('option:visible').first().attr('selected', 'selected');`

```
jQuery(".roomss option:first-child:visible").attr("selected", true);
```

Html:

```
<select name="room4" id="room4" class="roomss form-control placeholder-no-fix" style="display: inline; width: 30%;">
    <option value="1" class="roomnumber1">1</option>
    <option value="2" class="roomnumber2">2</option>
    <option value="3" class="roomnumber3">3</option>
    <option value="4" class="roomnumber4">4</option>
    <option value="5" class="roomnumber5">5</option>
    <option value="6" class="roomnumber6">6</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
        function checkRoom() {
            var date = document.getElementById("date4").value;
            var time = document.getElementById("time4").value;
            var str = date + " " + time + ":00.0";
            $('option.roomnumber1').show();
            $('option.roomnumber2').show();
            $('option.roomnumber3').show();
            $('option.roomnumber4').show();
            $('option.roomnumber5').show();
            $('option.roomnumber6').show();
            for(var i = 0; i < orderids.length; i++) {
                if(str === scheduledates[i]) {
                    if(rooms[i] !== "null") {
                        $('option.roomnumber' + rooms[i]).hide();
                    }
                }
            }
            // insert code that sets first visible option as default value
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

try following:

```
$(".roomss option:visible:first").attr("selected", "selected");
```

for new version of jQuery

```
$(".roomss option:visible:first").prop("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: How come I am still seeing `1` as the default value even in the jsfiddle

Comment: I see 4 as selected...which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: it is working fine in Firefox..let me update it for Chrome